# adding images dynamically to an openerp rml report file

Tags: report, odoo, rml

I want to do something like this in a openerp report, how would I need to go about to create this file path:

```
<image file="images\[[o.name]]" x="72" y="72"/>
```

Are there ways to create variables in rml that I could then feed to the file= attribute.

I have little to no python knowledge, but would love to get this solved.

Right now I am trying to adjust the order.rml, I can load images, but only statically ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the reports .py file add a python function like this:

```
self.localcontext.update({
            'time': time,
            'image_url' : self._get_imagepath,
        })

def _get_imagepath(self,product):
        attach_ids = self.pool.get('ir.attachment').search(self.cr, self.uid, [('res_model','=','product.product'), ('res_id', '=',product)])
        datas = self.pool.get('ir.attachment').read(self.cr, self.uid, attach_ids)
        if len(datas):
            # if there are several, pick first
            try:
                if datas[0]['link']:
                    try:
                        img_data =  base64.encodestring(urllib.urlopen(datas[0]['link']).read())
                        return img_data
                    except Exception,innerEx:
                        print innerEx
                elif datas[0]['datas']:
                    return datas[0]['datas']
            except Exception,e:
                print e
        return None
```

in the rml itself call the function as such:

```
<para>[[ image_url(o['id']) and setTag('para','image') or removeParentNode('para') ]][[ image_url(o['id']) ]]</para>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just do

```
<image>o.company_id.logo</image>
```

or reference your image in whatever way makes sense, that one will display the company logo on an order form, you could add image fields to your products and display those on the line items of the order if you want.

Answer (score 1):

also you can do the following in

```
<header> 
<pageTemplate>
<frame id="first" x1="1.3cm" y1="2.5cm" height="23.0cm" width="19cm"/>
  <pageGraphics>
    <image file= "/home/workspace/openERP/src/openerp-server/pixmaps/client-logo.png"    x="3.3cm" y="3.5cm" height="32.0"/>
  </pageGraphics> 
</pageTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I can not comment on Alan Bell's solution, I'm afraid I have to correct him in a separate answer.

Alan wrote you can just use:

```
<image>o.company_id.logo</image>
```

This is not entirely correct; you need to enclose the expression in double square brackets like so:

```
<image>[[ o.company_id.logo ]]</image>
```

For the attributes you can pass to the image tag, I redirect you towards the RML documentation: http://www.reportlab.com/docs/rml2pdf-userguide.pdf